# Can I override Material-UI with css modules in create-react-app v2?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, css-modules

For example I want to add margin-top to this button

```
import classes from 'button.module.css';
        <Button 
          type="submit"
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          fullWidth
          disabled={this.props.isLoading}
          className={classes.Button}
        >
          {this.props.isLoading ? <CircularProgress size={20}/> : 'SIGN IN'}
        </Button>
```

In button.module.css file

```
.Button {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Is this possible to use this method instead of override like instruction in official material-ui page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my recent project i did things like

`import './style.css';`

where this is example content of style.css

```
.detailbox-paper {
  width: 90vw;
  margin: 20px auto 0px auto;
}
```

where i consumed it by using a className on the element like this
`<Paper className="detailbox-paper">`
and it worked. One thing to keep in mind by this approach, is the css specificity you are then starting to fight with.

You can also use inline `styles={{}}` with the camelCase syntax for attributes. But, as far as i know, inline styles always will be set, exept there is the `!important` keyword.

Hopefully this could help you on your journey.

Comment: yeah I used inline styling and it works. I can also override the <Paper> component with external css but somehow the Button component doesn't apply my style

Comment: its a css specifity problem, you will need higher weight or important. have a look at https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/ if you dont already know it ;-)

Comment: after adding !important everything is working now. Thank you very much, I completely forgot about the specify problems. Your answer really helps XD

Comment: If you're having troubles with specificity check out the "internal states" section below  https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/#overriding-with-inline-style

Comment: yes, this definitely works but you should be aware that this approach creates global styles, not a local scoped styles (CSS modules)

Answer (score 15):

Simply use `StylesProvider` component with the `injectFirst` property:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './App'
import { StylesProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles" // <-- import this component, and wrap your App.

ReactDOM.render(
    <StylesProvider injectFirst>
        <App />
    </StylesProvider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

It's a problem of CSS specificity, in which your CSS is loaded before the Material UI's styles, and therefore is overridden by them. As stated in the [docs](https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#stylesprovider), regarding the `injectFirst` property:

> By default, the styles are injected last in the  element of the
> page. As a result, they gain more specificity than any other style
> sheet. If you want to override Material-UI's styles, set this prop.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can.

Use `className` like you normally you do with CRA.

[This](https://material-ui.com/guides/interoperability/#css-modules) will explain how to use CSS modules. This is straightforward.

However, after doing the above-mentioned thing, I had an issue of my CSS getting overridden by MaterialUI CSS. So we need to change the order of Styleinjection.

[This](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#css-injection-order) explains how you can do this.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/5km241l9xn) is a sandbox with a working sample.

Comment: The sandbox doesn't work anymore for MUI 5.0, solution for v5: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/24109